# Why does this nested typeclass derivation work?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

Yeah, it's the unusual "why does this work" question.
I have this piece of code:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

data F a = A (F a) | B (a (F a)) -- a :: * -> *
deriving instance (forall b. Eq b => Eq (a b)) => Eq (F a)

-- the following errors, asking me to add (Eq b) into the context
deriving instance (forall b. Eq (a b)) => Eq (F a)
```

The second version errors out if one define

```hs
data T a = C | D a deriving Eq
x = B C == B C
```

From a logical aspect, adding `(Eq b)` to the constraints should be something like `(forall b. Eq b && Eq (a b)) => Eq (F a)`, because we need to keep it in the scope of `forall`. It is conceivable that `(Eq b)` is assumed implicitly, as most deriving instances do. But if so, why doesn't the second version work?

Comment: As a side note, can anyone point out why, apart from some annoying haskell extension flags, the class `Show1` should ever be used instead of this?

Comment: You can see what deriving clauses GHC emits with `:set -ddump-deriv`

Comment: If you want to highlight that `a :: Type -> Type` you could rename it to `f` and give a kind signature `type F :: (Type -> Type) -> Type`

Comment: @Iceland_jack The deriving clauses is just as one would expect. That's a really useful flag for debugging though ;)

Comment: As for `Eq1`, and `Show1` here is Edward Kmett answering my question if they can be replaced by quantified constraints: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/jgjo8w/is_there_a_cofreet_with_a_more_intuitive/g9t6ybw/?context=3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first deriving equals the following instance

```
instance (forall b. Eq b => Eq (f b)) => Eq (F f) where
  (==) :: F f -> F f -> Bool
  A a1 == A b1 = (==) @(F f)     a1 b1
  B a1 == B b1 = (==) @(f (F f)) a1 b1
  _    == _    = False
```

Given that equality is closed under *f* (`forall b. Eq b => Eq (f b)`) the following constraints are wanted from `(==) @(F f)` and `(==) @(f (F f))`

1. `Eq (F f)`
2. `Eq (f (F f))`

For the first one is the equality instance we are writing/deriving: `Eq (F f)` which holds in the current context (`Eq` is closed under *f*). So that constraint is satisfied.

The second one asks for equality for our lifted type: `Eq (f (F f))` which follows from the context: `Eq` being closed under *f*.

If we instantiate *b* with `F f` we see that our lifted type supports equality `Eq (F f) => Eq (f (F f))` if the type we are defining supports equlity.. which it does (*1.*).

---

The second instance compiles on GHC Head.

```
deriving instance (forall b. Eq (f b)) => Eq (F f)
```

If you know that `Eq (f b)` holds for any *b*, you can solve *1.* and *2.* by instantiating *b* with `F f`.

Comment: If you remove the `(Eq b)` part, shouldn't it be a stronger premise? Why wouldn't GHC accept that deriving instance?

Comment: As far as I see it does

Comment: After checking my code, I see it's a slightly different error. I'm updating this question. Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

After playing around for a little bit, I think I nailed down the problem. Sorry for editing the question frequently! I oversimplified the code, and didn't test carefully.

The `data T a = C | D a` derives an `Eq` instance that requires `Eq a`. Without that, the `forall b. Eq (T b)` premise cannot be satisfied. With `forall b. (Eq b) => Eq (T b)`, we can use `Eq b` to obtain the required equality predicate on `a`.

Comment: Your `T` = `Maybe`, and yes comparing `B Nothing == B Nothing` with the second instance will fail as there is it requires `Eq` on the element type. The other way around is fine, the first instance assumes an `Eq` instance in its context, this is the same as providing an `Eq` instance but we are free to ignore it like in `B Proxy == B Proxy` (with first instance).